# How do I open a file using the shell's default handler?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Our client (a winforms app) includes a file-browser.  I'd like the user to be able to open the selected file using the shell's default handler.  How do I do that?  I've read that I should use the Win32 API rather than the registry, but I'd prefer a solution that involves only .NET.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

EDIT: Newer, simpler answer.

You can indeed just use `Process.Start(filename)`. This is specified in the [docs for `Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s.aspx):

> Starting a process by specifying its
>   file name is similar to typing the
>   information in the Run dialog box of
>   the Windows Start menu. Therefore, the
>   file name does not need to represent
>   an executable file. It can be of any
>   file type for which the extension has
>   been associated with an application
>   installed on the system. For example
>   the file name can have a .txt
>   extension if you have associated text
>   files with an editor, such as Notepad,
>   or it can have a .doc if you have
>   associated.doc files with a word
>   processing tool, such as Microsoft
>   Word. Similarly, in the same way that
>   the Run dialog box can accept an
>   executable file name with or without
>   the .exe extension, the .exe extension
>   is optional in the fileName parameter.
>   For example, you can set the fileName
>   parameter to either "Notepad.exe" or
>   "Notepad".

EDIT: Original, complicated answer:

If you use `Process.Start` with the file as the "executable" and specify `UseShellExecute = true` it will just work. For example:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("test.txt");
        psi.UseShellExecute = true;
        Process.Start(psi);
    }
}
```

That opens test.txt in Notepad.

In fact, `UseShellExecute=true` is the default, but as it's definitely required I like to specify it explicitly to make that clearer to the reader.

Comment: `Process.Start("C:\temp\test.xlsx");` open a ***xlsx file*** if **Excel is installed**. If not installed, I don't know.

Comment: Your old answer is now very relevant for dotnet core apps, where `UseShellExecute=true` is required, again.

Answer (score 8):

Since this question is the first result in Google, I'm adding this updated answer for .NET Core and .NET 5 upwards. You will need to add `UseShellExecute = true`.

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(filePath) { UseShellExecute = true });
```

It's more cumbersome than earlier with .NET Framework, but you can wrap it in a custom method:

```
    public static void OpenFile(string filePath) 
        => Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(filePath) { UseShellExecute = true });
```

Answer (score 7):

not sure if its ok

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filePath);
```

Answer (score 3):

System.Diagnostics.Process provides the .Net native wrapper around shell32.ShellExecute.

See [PInvoke.Net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32.ShellExecute) for a discussion of both APIs, and MSDN docs on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s.aspx) .