# Starting a native WindowsApp returns denied access

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I'd like to start the ScreenSketch.exe windows app via Shell, but the directory is denied:

```
    var allFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Program Files\WindowsApps", "ScreenSketch.exe", 
    System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    // Directory WindowsApps is denied
    if (allFiles.Length > 0)
    {
       allFiles[0].ShellOpen(); // ShellOpen is an extension method
    }
```

Message:

HResult=0x80070005
  Message=Access to the path 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps' is denied.

Comment: I believe it's because you're trying to `Get` the file. Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/811521/how-do-i-open-a-file-using-the-shells-default-handler .

Comment: @"C:\Program Files\WindowsApps" has access denied, because of whit it not list the directory.